# Select from a Hive Table where date less than max date

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to select * from a Hive table where a date column called TRANS_DATE say is >= than the 365 days before the maximum TRANS_DATE.

Below is the query I've tried so far:

```
select * from TABLE
where (TRANS_DATE > DATE_SUB(max(TRANS_DATE), 365)) and 
        (TRANS_DATE < max(TRANS_DATE));
```

Below is the error I have gotten:
"Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 2:28 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'max'"

An example of the date format is: "2006-05-30 00:00:00.0"

The query is to be to read data from a hive table into Qlikview so ideally I'd like not to define variables before hand and would prefer to do the select dynamically. Apologies if any of this is daft as I'm new to Hive.

Comment: This is an invalid query on any database, including Oracle.

Comment: Invalid how? As in it can't be done?

Comment: As in invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculate max_date in a subquery and cross join with table:

```
select * 
  from TABLE a
       cross join --cross join with single row
       (select max(TRANS_DATE) as max_trans_date from TABLE) b 
 where (a.TRANS_DATE > DATE_SUB(b.max_trans_date, 365)) 
   and (a.TRANS_DATE < b.max_trans_date);
```

With analytic function:

```
select a.* from
(select a.*,
       max(TRANS_DATE) over() as max_trans_date 
  from TABLE a) a
 where (a.TRANS_DATE > DATE_SUB(a.max_trans_date, 365)) 
   and (a.TRANS_DATE < a.max_trans_date);
```

Comment: Thanks for this leftjoin, having used Oracle SQL in the past I thought I'd be able to do simple where date < max date but apparently not. Anyway your solution works so thank you for this.

Comment: Windows function

Comment: Added analytic function :)